# Как правильно уйти от дублирования кода в sqlite с callback

Tags: javascript, sqlite, callback

Как правильней  и проще переписать, если в кусок кода 3 куча обращений к переменным, объявленным выше начала транзакции?

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(select...,function(tx,rs){
    if rs.item.length = 0 
        tx.executesql('insert....', params1, function (tx,rs) {
            кусок кода 1; 
            кусок кода 3
        }); 
    else 
        tx.executesql('update....', params2, function(tx,rs) {
            кусок кода 2; 
            кусок кода 3
        });
},err, success);
```

Comment: Если честно, вообще ничего не понятно. Зачем это переписывать?

Comment: хотелось бы избавиться от дубля кусок кода3. изначально if else не было, это правка на скорую руку.

Comment: Вынесете этот кусок в функцию или оставьте после конструкции if else, раз в том или другом случае выполняется код... Но все конечно надо смотреть на месте и по коду. Так вот хз, что там у вас за код и на сколько сильно он привязан к контексту

Comment: а как за пределы if вынести,  когда это callback после executesql c использованием rs

Comment: Ну не знаю... присвоить значения tx, rs внешним переменным допустим. Хотя более логичным выглядит запихивание куска 3 в отедельную функцию с передачей нужных аргументов. Однако еще раз... Надо смотреть по самому коду, на сколько сильно он привязан к контексту и внешнему окружению.

Comment: Я js  плохо знаю, думал, что может с помощью каких - нибудь промисов или await  можно как-то поставить на паузу и вытащить кусок 3 наружу.

Comment: Можно и промисами, но это будет то же внешняя функция, куда надо передать необходимые параметры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможные варианты для того, что бы избавиться от дублирования кода:

##### Первый

Можно создать отдельную функцию и в нее передать нужные аргументы для выполнения

```
function three(tx, rs) {
  // Кусок кода 3
};

db.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('sql', function (tx, rs) {
    if (rs.item.length = 0) {
      tx.executesql('insert....', params1, function (tx, rs) {
        // Некий кусок 1
        three(tx, rs);
      });
    } else {
      tx.executesql('update....', params2, function (tx, rs) {
        // Некий кусок 2
        three(tx, rs);
      });
    }
  }, err, success)
};
```

##### Второй

Создать промис(ниже пример явного создания промиса, можно это сделать обычной асинхронной фукнцией)

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql('sql', function (tx, rs) {
    function doSome(tx, rs) {
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        if (rs.item.length = 0) {
          tx.executesql('insert....', params1, function (tx, rs) {
            // Некий кусок 1
            res({ tx, rs });
            // Если возникла ошибка, можно вернуть ошибку
            rej('someError');
          });
        } else {
          tx.executesql('update....', params2, function (tx, rs) {
            // Некий кусок 2
            res({ tx, rs });
            // Если возникла ошибка, можно вернуть ошибку
            rej('someError');
          });
        }
      })
    }
    doSome(tx, rs)
      .then(res => {
        // А тут кусок кода 3
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // Что то делаем, если ошибка
      });

  }, err, success)
};
```

Если надо передавать большее число параметров в фукнцию, то можно пойти 2мя путями:

1. Явно объявить в фукнции передаваемые параметры
2. Собрать параметры в массив переданных аргументов и работать с ними

Пример по второму способу

```js
function zz(a, b, ...c) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
  console.log(c[2]); // Вернет 5, т.к. это 3й элемент от остатка
}
zz(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

function vv(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b, arguments);
  console.log(arguments[2]); // Вернет 30, т.к. это 3й переданный агрумент в функцию
}

vv(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70);
```

Какая из реализаций вам более подходит, выбирать вам.

Comment: Второй вариант - то, что надо. Только не понял, почему тут два параметра Promise((res, rej)?

Comment: @Djames Если у вас возникнет ошибка в процессе выполнения, вы можете инициировать возврат ошибки из промиса, это будет выглядеть аналогично `res()` -> `rej(errorMessage)` и перехватывать ее можно в `.catch()`. В errorMessage передаете необходимые данные, для обработки ошибки. Ответ чуток подправил, что было нагляднее

Comment: Все, понял, это свойства самого промиса. Спасибо.

Comment: @Djames Если ответ вам подходит, отметьте его как приняты слева от ответа(галочка). За хороший ответ, можо даже проголосовать(стрелочка вверх). Здесь, это лучшее спасибо!